# Optimizing several MySQL (sub-)Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some big problems to find the best way for getting one big Table with my users plays:

The functionality works this way: People can play two different games and earn playmoney with this. Additional, they have referred user, from which they also gain amounts to their balance. My current query takes forever and looks like this:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT 
    n.id, n.account, n.email, n.lastpayout, n.referupnumber, 
    (SELECT sum(r.win) FROM rolls r WHERE r.konto = n.id AND r.zeit > n.lastpayout) as sumroll,
    (SELECT sum(m.gewinn) FROM multi m WHERE m.account = n.id AND m.zeit > n.lastpayout) as summulti,
    (SELECT count(nx.referupnumber) FROM nxt_account nx WHERE nx.referupnumber = n.id) as amountref
FROM
    nxt_account n");

$amountuser = $sql->num_rows;
$c = 1;  
while($row = $sql->fetch_array()) {

    $id_thistime = $row['id'];
    $sql_ref = $mysqli->query("SELECT 
    nn.id,
    (SELECT 
            sum(rr.win)
        FROM
            rolls rr
        WHERE
            rr.zeit >= nn.lastpayout AND rr.konto = n.id) as refamount
FROM
    nxt_account nn
WHERE
    nn.referupnumber = '".$id_thistime."'");
    $total_ref = 0;

while($row_ref = $sql_ref->fetch_array()) {

    $total_ref = $total_ref + $row_ref['refamount'];

}

$total_amount = $row['sumroll'] + $row['summulti'] + $total_ref;   }
```

Comment: It looks like SQL in the main `while` is duplicating the first sub-query. If it is not exactly the same calculation you should still incorporate it in the main query.

Comment: Both answers below did help out finding way better queries. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change your main query to this and make all calculations from one database request:

```
    SELECT 
        n.id, n.account, n.email, n.lastpayout, n.referupnumber, 
        (SELECT sum(r.win) 
         FROM rolls r 
         WHERE r.konto = n.id AND r.zeit > n.lastpayout) as sumroll,
        (SELECT sum(m.gewinn) 
         FROM multi m 
         WHERE m.account = n.id AND m.zeit > n.lastpayout) as summulti,
        (SELECT count(nx.referupnumber) 
         FROM nxt_account nx 
         WHERE nx.referupnumber = n.id) as amountref,
        (SELECT sum(rr.win)
         FROM  rolls rr INNER JOIN nxt_account nn ON
            rr.zeit >= nn.lastpayout AND rr.konto = n.id
         WHERE nn.referupnumber =n.id) as refamount
    FROM
        nxt_account n
```

The way it is done you have as many requests as there are records in the `nxt_account` table. This is probably the main reason why calculation is slow.

If you just need one number of totals for all accounts, you should do that calculation in SQL also.

Comment: Thank you. This was already very helpful. I had to do some small changes but the overall query looks nice! For example lastpayout in the JOIN should not be the individual referral user but the user selected above, so its n.referupnumber.
I placed the rr.zeit>nn.lastpayout in the WHERE JOIN clause, instead of ON. But with these small changes its working

Answer (score 2):

This is the query:

```
SELECT n.id, n.account, n.email, n.lastpayout, n.referupnumber, 
       (SELECT sum(r.win) FROM rolls r WHERE r.konto = n.id AND r.zeit > n.lastpayout) as sumroll,
       (SELECT sum(m.gewinn) FROM multi m WHERE m.account = n.id AND m.zeit > n.lastpayout) as summulti,
       (SELECT count(nx.referupnumber) FROM nxt_account nx WHERE nx.referupnumber = n.id) as amountref
FROM nxt_account n;
```

You are bringing in data from multiple tables, so this is a reasonable structure.  I would recommend the following indexes:

```
rolls(konto, zeit, win)
multi(account, zeit, gewinn)
nxt_account(referupnumber)
```

This should speed the subqueries and improve performance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first two indexes? I can understand how having the columns used in the WHERE in the index helps the engine. But how does the last column (the one to SUM) help? Does the engine avoid accessing the table because it finds the value to SUM in the index?

Comment: Thank you so far. One of the biggest delay come from referral earnings. So as you can see I have created a new query, for every query to check, if the person from nxt_account has any referred user. The subquery goes into each referred user and checks how much he has earned. This takes up most from the time. This is not solved yet, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Frazz . . . Yes, you are on the right track.  The entire query can be satisfied by the index, so the original data pages are not needed.  This should result in better performance.

Comment: @Tosch . . . This doesn't take into account the processing for the last query, but Bulat is correct that you should do it all in one query.

Comment: Wow, I just had the live example. First running the queries without indexing, it still took a lot time. After using the index it improve the performance heavily. Thanks for this hint!